# Short Term/Intraday Momentum Strategies

Tags: high-frequency, momentum

I am currently interested in doing some research on short term/intraday momentum trading strategies (highly liquid large cap stocks), especially to test if there are profitable strategies on higher frequency data (e.g. 5 minutes) using technical indicators like RSI or MACD.

Do you have good studies/overview studies/authors in mind that give a good overview of the current state of the literature? One example would be Schulmeister, 2009: Profitability of technical stock trading: has it moved from daily to intraday data? (RFE).

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
All the best

Comment: The research on these topics is limited. There are 2 main reasons: first, for a long while academia just didn't have the data with that resolution. Second, on this scale your order execution technique becomes as important as the alpha itself and again it's mostly outside of scope of most academic research.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The research plan is nothing fancy, just trying to find out what the current literature says about intraday momentum and if there are any meaningful strategies, perhaps with technical indicators, to be tested on my own data. It's more about getting to know the current literature and implement some models for fun.

Still, any suggestions on current literature would be greatly appreciated. Thanks